# Expected identifier for [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]]

Tags: ios, uitableview

I keep getting Expected Identifier in my if statement

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell1";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        //NSDate *object = _objects[indexPath.row];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]];
        // expected identifier
    }
```

Comment: I don't know why you're getting that, but when you use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath, you don't need that if clause at all. That dequeue method is guaranteed to create a cell.

Comment: ok. I removed the offending code. Put that as an answer so I can give you credit

Comment: @CocoaDev That's not the problem, nor is it the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here:

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]];
       ^                                                                                                  ^
```

You have an extra pair of brackets. The outermost pair is superfluous.

Comment: I didn't think that would matter much but it looks like it did! Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why you're getting that, but when you use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath, you don't need that if clause at all. That dequeue method is guaranteed to create a cell.

Comment: that is true when you also use `registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier`

Comment: or when you're using storyboards with custom cells that have identifiers.

Comment: @andreagiavatto, you don't need to do that (despite what the documentation says) if you've created your cell in a storyboard.

Answer (score -1):

You are dequeueing a cell with the identifier "Cell" and creating a new one with identifier "Cell1" that's why you always end up in the if statement.

Change

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

to

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question about the syntax error either.